# Sqlite bindings for OCaml

Tags: sqlite, ocaml

I have been looking for SQLite bindings for OCaml. I stumbled upon [ocaml-sqlite3](http://caml.inria.fr/cgi-bin/hump.en.cgi?contrib=471) which looks good and current, but there is no documentation whatsoever about how to use it.

There is some very old documentation (API reference only) of [an obsolete ocaml-sqlite binding](http://neugierig.org/software/ocaml/sqlite) that was discontinued in 2004. But it really doesn't look current and probably is already quite different from the updated version I found (listed in the above link).

I was just wondering if anybody has some documentation, examples or clue at all of how these libraries work. I could go through the code, but I'd like to keep that option as the last resource.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Howdy. The ocaml-sqlite3 library you mentioned does, in fact, have documention; you just have to build it with `make doc`. It's included in the comments in the `.mli` file as well; you can have a look here: http://hg.ocaml.info/release/ocaml-sqlite3/file/b28bff3ff215/sqlite3.mli . I realize it's basically just an API reference, but it looks fairly comprehensive.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I completely overlooked the fact that I can build the docs! Makes more sense now.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to phooji's answer, please note that the API follows closely the C sqlite library. Thus, any Sqlite book should help you to use the OCaml binding. And you are correct about which version to use; the one here: http://www.ocaml.info/home/ocaml_sources.html.